# Helm chart version and patch wildcard

Tags: azure-container-registry, helm3, acr

With Helm 2, we were able to use "wildcard versions", so that always the latest version would have been used (index.yaml based repository). E.g. if there are charts with versions 0.2.0, 0.2.1 and 0.2.2, `--version ^v0.2` would pull 0.2.2

Now changing to Helm 3 with a OCI repository (ACR on Azure), this seems not to work any more:

> Error: Failed to render chart: exit status 1: Error: failed to
> download "oci://my-repo.azurecr.io/helm/my-chart" at version "^v0.2"

Is there no way to use wildcards for patch version with OCI repositories? I also tried `~0.2`.

A workaround might be to produce a duplicate helm chart with tag 0.2, but I don't like this idea much ...

Comment: I have a more specific but somewhat related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71861292/how-do-i-specify-the-latest-build-number-in-chart-yaml-and-command-line. https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/10862

Answer (score 0):

Tested with `helm 3.9.0`:

```
helm pull oci://ghcr.io/rowi1de/graphql-reactive/graphql-reactive --version '0.0.*'
```

Pulled: ghcr.io/rowi1de/graphql-reactive/graphql-reactive:0.0.17

Digest: sha256:3597cf575d98f4adb426ed8ad37e34d5b6cf452a86ccc2da64b0471aedd9dcba